# Convert a Large .txt file to a ophcrack rainbow table

Tags: linux, windows, passwords

I have made a txt file with some passwords in it and i need a way to convert it into a rainbow tables to crack windows passwords using ophcrack. I have had a look on Google but i haven't found a way to do this. My OS is windows 7 but i can use Ubuntu if needed. Can any one help.

Comment: Did you tried [this](http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/rainbow-tables-create-use-them-crack-passwords-0131470/)?

Comment: @RenjuChandranchingath Yes but there is now way to convert a txt file in to a table.

Comment: What about using [Genpmk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEvOtFYzmIk) and [cowpatty](http://airodump.net/cracking-wpa-psk-wifi-security/)?. I never had a try with these tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source [Rainbow Tables](https://sites.google.com/site/reusablesec/Home/rainbow-tables)

**dcrack allows the creation and use of dictionary based rainbow tables**

> Supported Systems:
>
> Config Generator and Multi-Threaded Version
>
> - Most flavors of Linux
> - MacOSX
>
> Creating Rainbow Tables
>
> usage: drtgen
>
> ...
>
> Options For Dictionary Based Tables
>
> -d (REQUIRED):Tell drtgen that this is a dictionary based attack
>
> -dic  (REQUIRED):The name of the input dictionary to use

Using this option you can enter the name of your dictionary.

Comment: Thanks its a bit slow but its getting there.

Comment: Please let me know if it worked.

Comment: I will, Its still going.